# Аналог Padding в RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Когда задан Padding для параграфа, то его формат передается следующей строке, после нажатия <kbd>Enter</kbd>. И убрать его получается только вручную.

```
<Paragraph Padding="0,50,0,0">
      <Run Text="Spacing between paragraphs is caused by margins set on the paragraphs."/>
</Paragraph>

myRichTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Paragraph.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(0));
```

Вот как бы это сделать автоматом? Или вовсе не использовать Padding, а сделать вставку с такими же свойствами: чтобы не выделялась и чтобы каретка не перемещалась по ее боковым сторонам.

Comment: не совсем понятен вопрос, есть возможность добавить гифку?

Comment: Добавил картинку. С гифкой не стал заморачиваться, давно ничего такого не делал) В Word также: Padding "наследуется" следующей строкой. А хотелось бы как на картинке ниже черты.